# Laravel: Custom error message for each Controller?

Tags: laravel, controller, each

This is code in /resource/lang/en/validation.php for custom error message for each specify element name and validation rule:

```
'custom' => [
    'attribute-name' => [
        'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
    ],
],
```

But this is my problem. I have:

- Controller A -> element [title] -> require -> message 'AAA'
- Controller B -> element [title] -> require -> message 'BBB'

But because some reasons, **I don't want to custom error message in method messages() in Request class**.

I need to custom message in /resource/lang/en/validation.php. How can I do that? Pseudo-code:

```
ControllerA.title.require => 'AAA'
ControllerB.title.require => 'BBB
```

'
Please help me. And thank you so much.

Comment: As per my understanding I think this is not possible by the validiaiton.php  because in custom array we have to provide the attribute_name , rule_name and then the specific message for that rule. And as per your question you have the same name of attribute that is `title.` So may first message will return every time.

Comment: If you want the different messages for different controller then create different request for each controller if you are using the **laravel >= 5.1** and in that request class you can override the `rules` and `messages()` function. So the messages which you have wrote in request class those will return when the validation is applied.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve custom messages is to specify your custom message at time of validation, e.g:

```
// custom messages
$messages = [ 'rule-name' => 'Custom message' ];

// validate input with rules, adding in custom messages
$validation = Validator::make( Input::all(), $rules, $messages );
```

The third parameter `$messages` in `Validator::make` lets you pass in an array of custom messages. You can even add in replacements, e.g.:

```
$messages = [ 'rule-name' => 'Custom message for :attribute should be :value' ];
```

You can even specify custom messages for different validation issues for the same field:

```
$messages = [
    'field.required' => 'Field is required',
    'field.size' => Field is too short' 
];
```